# Error in Flutter code " type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool' "?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, boolean, flutter-design

I am creating a multi-paged app on flutter to To determine the time based on the location, but when the code is turned on, there's a problem on this page, I tried to fix the problem, but the error still exists" type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'" I'll include the other pages in the comments.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
    }
    
    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
       Map? data={};
      @override
    
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    
           if (data!= null) {
            data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map?;}
    
        // set background image
        final  String? bgImage = data?['isDayTime'] ? 'day.png' : 'night.png';
        final Color? bgColor =  data?['isDayTime'] ? Colors.blue : Colors.indigo[700];
    
         return Scaffold(
           backgroundColor: bgColor,
           body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('asset/$bgImage'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 120.0, 0, 0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        dynamic result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
                        if(result != null){
                          setState(() {
                            data = {
                              'Time': result['Time'],
                              'Location': result['Location'],
                              'isDayTime': result['isDayTime'],
                              'Flag': result['Flag']
                            };
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.edit_location,
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                      ),
                      label: Text(
                        'Edit Location',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[300],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          data?['Location'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 28.0,
                            letterSpacing: 2.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Text(
                        data?['Time'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 66.0,
                            color: Colors.white
                        )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: class WorldTime{
  String Location ;
  late String Time;
  String Flag ;
  String Url ;
  late bool isDayTime;
  WorldTime({ required this.Location, required this.Flag,required this.Url});
  Future<void> getTime() async {
    // make the request

Comment: Future<void> getTime() async {
 try { Response response = await get(
          Uri.parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$Url'));
      Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      String datetime = data['datetime'];
      String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(0, 3);
      DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
      now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));
      isDayTime = now.hour > 6 && now.hour < 20 ? true : false;
      Time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
      Time = 'could not get time';

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type Null is not a subtype of type int error when tried fetch data from an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67917585/type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-int-error-when-tried-fetch-data-from-an-api)

Answer (score 1):

Your data is of type Map, and if the data does not have `isDayTime` field than it is returning `null` and, ternary operator decision can not be made on `null`.
So, to fix this either you can check whether your data map have the filed using `data.containsKey('isDayTime')` or You can use `??` (null aware operator) to assign a `fallback` value, so that your ternary operator will always have `boolean` value.

Comment: thanks but This error has appeared After I followed your instructions "Null check operator used on a null value "what is the problem?

Comment: Can you share that line of code where it throwing  "Null check operator used on a null value"?

Comment: ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building Home(dirty, dependencies: [_ModalScopeStatus], state: _HomeState#407e3):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Home Home:file:///C:/Users/96278/Desktop/worldtime/lib/main.dart:12:29

Comment: This issue is in main.dart file, line no 12, Can you share main.dart file code?

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:worldtime/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:worldtime/pages/loading.dart';
import 'package:worldtime/pages/location.dart';


void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/home',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => Loading(),
      '/home': (context) => Home(),
      '/location': (context) => Location(),
    }
));

Comment: I don't see any issue in main.dart file.

Comment: In Home's state you have created data variable and you have assigned it with empty map, so it will be never null.

your initial route is /home that means it is loading Home widget. but at initial route you can not pass any arguments, so ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map?; is having null value.

ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map?; will have value if you navigate with arguments like
Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/home',arguments:{});
than in the landing page you can use ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map?; to get the passed arguments.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments.

Comment: Use FutureBuilder/StreamBuilder based on your need.

Answer (score 0):

1- `data?['isDayTime']` to `(data?['isDayTime']?? false)`

2- I think the wrong in variable (isDayTime)
so  you shouldn't use (late) key so if you are sure 100% you will declare this variable
so remove late and change it to final if it is't changing again

3- convert this
Map? data={}; to Map data={};
because this is already declared
and look at this link https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: thanks first of all 1 - I modified it 2- late using for null safety so I have to give the  (isDayTime) initial value (EX: false) or use late .3 when I remove the?  this appears ( Error: A value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' because 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?' is nullable and 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' isn't.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
        final  String? bgImage = data?['isDayTime'] ? 'day.png' : 'night.png';
    final Color? bgColor =  data?['isDayTime'] ? Colors.blue : Colors.indigo[700];
```

write

```
        final  String? bgImage = (data?['isDayTime'] ?? false) ? 'day.png' : 'night.png';
    final Color? bgColor =  (data?['isDayTime'] ?? false) ? Colors.blue : Colors.indigo[700];
```

and also instead of

```
setState(() {
                        data = {
                          'Time': result['Time'],
                          'Location': result['Location'],
                          'isDayTime': result['isDayTime'],
                          'Flag': result['Flag']
                        };
                      });
```

write

```
setState(() {
                        data = {
                          'Time': result['Time'],
                          'Location': result['Location'],
                          'isDayTime': result['isDayTime'] ?? false,
                          'Flag': result['Flag']
                        };
                      });
```

Comment: thanks but This error has appeared After I followed your instructions " type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' "what is the problem?

Comment: data = {
                          'Time': result['Time'] ?? '',
                          'Location': result['Location'] ?? '',
                          'isDayTime': result['isDayTime'] ?? false,
                          'Flag': result['Flag'] ?? '',
                        };

Comment: @M Karimi  the same error still appear

Comment: This error appear, because in somewhere a String variable, get null value. You should check your variables and by helping ?? '' operator, resolve the error.