# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<Comic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I had some issue and cannot solve it when I followed Food App of EDMT Dev. I use Realtime database of Firebase to connect with my Flutter app but it returned Error "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast"

```
body: FutureBuilder(
    future: viewModel.displaygetComicList(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
      else
        {
          var lst = snapshot.data as List<Comic>;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: lst!=null?lst.length:0,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text(lst[index].category);
            }
          );
          //return Center(child: Text('Load ok'),);

        }
    }),
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type Null is not a subtype of type int error when tried fetch data from an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67917585/type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-int-error-when-tried-fetch-data-from-an-api)

Answer (score 1):

try to change

```
var lst = snapshot.data as List<Comic>;
```

to

```
var lst = snapshot.data as List<Comic>?;
```

This way you indicate that it's possible to be null. Your way you say it's definitely not null, but because it is it throws the error