# Flutter: type Null is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and mobile apps development.

So, I am stuck with this error for week, trying and reading the solution over here but still unable to solve my problem.

So, this the API that I want to get the value from:

> {"error":false,"errmsg":"","data":[{"site":"hadapan","data1":"25.00","data3":"0.00"}]}

And this the code I got from an example and edit to use from my api.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://localhost/data.php'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final String site;
  final int data1;
  final int data3;

  const Album({
    required this.site,
    required this.data1,
    required this.data3,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      site: json['data'][0]['site'] as String, //data
      data1: json['data'][0]['data1'] as int,
      data3: json['data'][0]['data3'] as int,
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.site); //I am trying to pass the data here
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope someone can point out where I do wrong.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You have problems with type casting, and in your JSON what should be numeric value is a string. You should parse that string to int.

Comment: Is it okay if I declare the numeric value as String instead of parse string to int? Since my JSON is in string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type Null is not a subtype of type int error when tried fetch data from an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67917585/type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-int-error-when-tried-fetch-data-from-an-api)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it Nullable For Example

**Replace this**

```
final String site;
final int data1;
final int data3;
```

**With This**

```
final String? site;
final int? data1;
final int? data3;
```

Comment: replacing String to String?, gives me this error, "error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'." on this line, return Text(snapshot.data!.site).

Comment: Thats beacuse you have to add ? in front of site and all the parameters declared above too like this **return Text(snapshot.data!.site?)**

Comment: adding ? to the site. I get too many error, 

**1. error: Expected to find ':'. (expected_token at [expetapp] lib\main.dart:76)**,

**2. error: Expected an identifier. (missing_identifier at [expetapp] lib\main.dart:76)**,
**3. error: Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. (non_bool_condition at [expetapp] lib\main.dart:76)**

Comment: Sorry Add a null check there **return Text(snapshot.data!.site!)** replace **?** with **!**

Answer (score 2):

I think some of the values came as null
you probably should make the properties nullable
ex:
final int? data1;

Answer (score -1):

Your API is blank, no data, please check your api  **https://localhost/data.php**

Comment: Did you just tried to check a `localhost` to find actual JSON data?