# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I found an error while testing my app:

```
PS C:\Expert1\Tvseries-master> flutter test --coverage
02:28 +26 -1: loading C:\Expert1\Tvseries-master\test\data\datasources\televisi_remote_data\televisi_remote_data_source_test.dart [E]
  Failed to load "C:\Expert1\Tvseries-master\test\data\datasources\televisi_remote_data\televisi_remote_data_source_test.dart": type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
  package:ditonton/data/models/televisi_model/televisi_detail_model.dart 50:20             new TelevisiDetailResponse.fromJson
  test\data\datasources\televisi_remote_data\televisi_remote_data_source_test.dart 118:52  main.<fn>  
  package:test_api                                                                         Declarer.group
  package:flutter_test/src/test_compat.dart 189:13                                         group      
  test\data\datasources\televisi_remote_data\televisi_remote_data_source_test.dart 116:3   main
```

What's the reason for the error? How do I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the "Type Null is not a subtype of type ..." error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67917585/how-to-solve-the-type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-error)

Comment: Share the code in `package:ditonton/data/models/televisi_model/televisi_detail_model.dart` especially the `fromJson` method. There lies the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Share your code to assist you

Answer (score 0):

in this file `package:ditonton/data/models/televisi_model/televisi_detail_model.dart 50:20 new TelevisiDetailResponse.fromJson`
a field is expecting a boolean value but it received a Null value. you can fix this by making the boolean field nullable. example: `bool? isWorking;`